# pipe the output of parec to sox

Tags: audio, pipe, pulseaudio, sox

`sox` is probably the one linux program that continues to frustrate me. At the same time, I am awed by what it can do, and I'd like to get close to being fluent in it, if not mastering it.

Today, I've spent about 2 hours trying to get `sox` to read bytes from `parec` via a pipe.

The `parec` bytes are a `pulseaudio` "sink". In order to get them flowing through the pipe, I used [this answer from askubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/a/60856/2473)

This is the command I've been using:

```
$ parec -d telephonControl.monitor | sox -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 - -t pulse hmm.ogg silence 1 0.50 0.1% 1 2.0 0.1% :             newfile : restart
```

and this is the error I get:

```
sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of  `-'
write() failed: Broken pipe
```

What's more, oggenc parses them just fine:

```
parec -d telephonControl.monitor | oggenc -b 192 -o telephonControl.ogg --raw -
Encoding standard input to 
         "telephonControl.ogg" 
at approximate bitrate 192 kbps (VBR encoding enabled)
```

I have absolutely no idea how to make `sox` digest those bytes.

```
$ parec -d telephonControl.monitor >> somebytes

$ soxi somebytes
soxi FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `somebytes'
```

But I do know that they are raw audio, 16 bit signed little endian, 2 channel 44100kHz:

```
$pacmd
>>> list-sink-inputs
1 sink input(s) available.
    index: 17
        driver: <protocol-native.c>
        flags: 
        state: RUNNING
        sink: 2 <telephonControl>
        volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
                0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        muted: no
        current latency: 92.86 ms
        requested latency: 23.20 ms
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        resample method: (null)
        module: 7
        client: 53 <ALSA plug-in>
        properties:
                media.name = "ALSA Playback"
                application.name = "ALSA plug-in"
                native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
                native-protocol.version = "26"
                application.process.id = "3609"
                application.process.user = "alec"
                application.process.host = "ROOROO"
                window.x11.display = ":0"
                application.language = "en_GB.UTF-8"
                application.process.machine_id = "eec7c6ae60f90bb3921ad16d0000302d"
                application.process.session_id = "eec7c6ae60f90bb3921ad16d0000302d-1345384044.64188-1149507345"
                module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:ALSA plug-in"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-t` option needs to come *before* the filename it applies to.  Also, `-t pulse` means to read directly from (or write to) the PulseAudio daemon; it's not a file format as such.  The type name for raw audio is `raw`.

Try this:

```
parec ... | sox -t raw -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 - hmm.ogg ...
```

(where `...` means to keep the same arguments you had before)

`soxi` can't identify the filetype because all it does is look at the header.  Raw audio doesn't have a header for it to look at.

Comment: so argument order is key when dealing with sox... i've definitely learned my lesson!

Comment: Many `sox` options (including `-t`) can apply to either the input or the output.  The order of the arguments controls whether it's an input or output option.

Comment: I bumped into this post looking for playing direct from the stdin. Here is the command I used: `play -t raw -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 -`